# How to fix "Infinite loop caused by ordering" error in Django

Tags: django, django-models

When trying to create an instance of a model from the Django admin site on some models that are inherited according to a similar principle, the following error pops up:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3JOx.png)
Please tell me how can I fix this?

```
class Task(BaseEntity):
""" Задача - проведение каких либо работ
    BaseProperties: title, created_at, closed_at, author, description, comment, photo
    BaseEntity:
        Временные:                  date_start_work_p, date_start_work_f, date_end_work_p, date_end_work_f
        Сотрудники:                 curator, working_team, observers,
        Связи админ. сущностей:     lead_source
        Коммерческие:               client_LE, expenses_p, expenses_f, expenses_is_calculated, contract_price_p, contract_price_f

        __str__.title
    BaseHavingSlug: slug
    BaseHavingManager: manager, assistants
    BaseHavingParent: project_parent, deal_parent, stage_parent, task_parent
"""

type_task = models.ForeignKey('TypeTask', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='type_task', null=True, verbose_name='Тип Задачи')
working_status_task = models.ManyToManyField('WorkingStatusTask', related_name='working_status_task', verbose_name='Рабочие статусы')
closure_status_task = models.ForeignKey('ClosureStatusTask', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='closure_status_task',
                                        verbose_name='Статус закрытия', null=True, blank=True)
status_task = models.ForeignKey('StatusTask', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='status_task', null=True, verbose_name='Статус Задачи')

# если не null – связь по срокам
previous_task = models.ForeignKey('Task', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='previous_task_related', verbose_name='Предыдущая задача', null=True,
                                  blank=True)
# Как считать стоимость – в деньгах или в часах
in_money = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='В деньгах')
#   Затраченные рабочие часы
#   Изменить после заполнения можно только через согласование
working_hours_p = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Рабочие часы (план)', unique=True)
working_hours_f = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Рабочие часы (факт)', unique=True)
# Как считать ФОТ – от плана или от факта
salary_is_from_fact = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='В деньгах')
salary = MoneyField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4, default_currency='RUB', verbose_name='ФОТ', null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Задача"
    verbose_name_plural = "Задачи"
    ordering = ['-created_at']
```

Answer (score 1):

In models that have fields on themselves (in my case, they inherit), you need to use "self".Lol)

```
class BaseHavingParent(models.Model):
""" Для сущностей имеющих привязку к родителю """

lead_parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_lead_parent_related', verbose_name='В рамках Лида',
                                null=True, blank=True)
project_parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_project_parent_related', verbose_name='В рамках Проекта',
                                   null=True, blank=True)
```